# Hiding databases creates two servers localhost in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, linux, server, phpmyadmin

I added this line in my `config.inc.php` to hide the databases in `phpMyAdmin`:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = 'information_schema|performance_schema|mysql|phpmyadmin';
```

But now I'm getting a list of two servers called `localhost` when logging in:

[image]

One of them shows all databases. The other shows only the unhidden databases.

How can I get rid of this dropdown select, as it was before?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you've incremented `$i` somehow, making phpMyAdmin think that you meant to have two servers instead of one. You could edit your post to include your entire `config.inc.php` (obfuscating any sensitive information) and we'll look at it, but most often this occurs through an inadvertent copy and past such as this:

```
<?php
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'ireallylikemysportsteamandhopetheywin';

$i = 0;
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

In this case, the second `$i++;` should not be there.